# How to use multiple select conditions with JQ

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file something like below. Now I want to list where conditions is matching with type as `google_project_iam_binding` and delete or update.

With below jq I was able to get the details.

```
jq '.resource_changes[] | select(any(.change.actions[]; .=="delete" or .=="update"))'
```

With below jq select getting an error.

```
jq '.resource_changes[] | select((.type == "google_project_iam_binding") and (.change.actions[]; .=="delete" or .=="update"))'
```

```json
"resource_changes" : [
   {
      "address":"module.gke-cluster.module.gke.random_shuffle.available_zones",
      "module_address":"module.gke-cluster.module.gke",
      "mode":"managed",
      "type":"random_shuffle",
      "name":"available_zones",
      "provider_name":"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random",
      "change":{
         "actions":[
            "delete",
            "create"
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "address":"module.serviceproject.module.project-cfg.google_project_iam_binding.roles[\"roles/cloudkms.admin\"]",
      "module_address":"module.serviceproject.module.project-cfg",
      "mode":"managed",
      "type":"google_project_iam_binding",
      "name":"roles",
      "index":"roles/cloudkms.admin",
      "provider_name":"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google",
      "change":{
         "actions":[
            "delete"
            "update"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: The second approach is what you want, you're just missing the `any` keyword in front of the last opening paren. You might also make use of `IN(src; s)` which is a shortcut to `any(src == s; .)`, so that part could be rewritten as `… and IN(.change.actions[]; "delete", "update")`